# Logitstic Regression In Julia Returning Incorrect results

Tags: julia, economics

I am trying to use `optimize` from Julia's `Optim` package to estimate the vector `beta = [beta_0, beta_1]'` , but I am getting unreasonable results.

I've provided a minimum working example where the results estimate [27.04, -14.38] when the true values are [1, 1].

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a minimum working example. It's my first one, so please let me know how it could be improved.

```
using Distributions
using Optim
using LinearAlgebra
import Random

Random.seed!(42)

# generate data
true_beta = [1; 1];
N=500;
X = [ones(N) rand(Normal(0,1), N)];
u = rand(Normal(0,1), N)
# generate the latent variable
y_star = X * true_beta + u;
# generate observed variable
y = Vector{Int64}(zeros(N));
for i in 1:N
    if y_star[i] >= 0
        y[i] = 1
    end
end

# (negative of) loglikelihood function
function loglike(beta::Vector{Float64})
    l = Vector{Float64}()
    pk = 1/(1+exp(-X[i,:]'*beta))
    lhood = -y[i,1]*log(pk) - (1-y[i,1])*log(1-pk)
    for i in 1:size(y,1)
        push!(l, lhood)
    end
    return sum(l)
end

# initial guess: ols
ols = inv(X'X)X'y;
# minimize negative loglikelihood
res = optimize(loglike, ols)
# save parameter estimates of beta
betahat = res.minimizer
```

Comment: Why are the true values (in this example), `[1,1]` ?

Comment: I've updated the code to be more explicit. The true values are `[1; 1]` because the generating process of the latent variable is `y = X*beta + u` where `beta = [1; 1]`.

Comment: You have some performance traps here. You are accessing global variables inside your loop. That is a no-no, both with respect to performance and good programming practice. Secondly, you create and fill a vector needlessly. Just accumulate the sum into a scalar for each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your function is not defined correctly. It should be:

```
function loglike(beta::Vector{Float64})
    l = Vector{Float64}()
    for i in 1:size(y,1)
        pk = 1/(1+exp(-X[i,:]'*beta))
        lhood = -y[i]*log(pk) - (1-y[i])*log(1-pk)
        push!(l, lhood)
    end
    return sum(l)
end
```

And you can check that the result is correct by running:

```
using GLM
glm(@formula(y~x), (y=y, x=X[:, 2]), Binomial(), LogitLink())
```

Also notice that your data generating process is incorrect. You are adding normal noise and you should add logistic noise. With normal noise the correct model is Probit. If you use it e.g. like:

```
glm(@formula(y~x), (y=y, x=X[:, 2]), Binomial(), ProbitLink())
```

you will indeed recover both parameters to be around 1.

Comment: This solved the issue. Thank you. 
Your comment on the data generation process is insightful, too. The purpose of this exercise is to visualize the effects of misspecifying the assumptions about a random variable's error term.

Answer (score 0):

You may not get estimated values close to `[1, 1]` since you have used a step function to generate `y`.

Also, as suggested by @bogumił-kamiński, it is always better to use a tested function like `glm` from the `GLM` package. The GLM package not only provides estimates but an ecosystem surrounding the logistic regression, which is very useful to diagnose the model.

The `glm` produces the following

```
GeneralizedLinearModel

y ~ 1 + X

Coefficients:
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
               Coef.  Std. Error      z  Pr(>|z|)  Lower 95%  Upper 95%
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
(Intercept)  2.22148    0.193944  11.45    <1e-29    1.84136    2.6016
X            1.98917    0.223411   8.90    <1e-18    1.55129    2.42704
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

and estimates using a proper `loglike` function

```
julia> # save parameter estimates of beta
       betahat = res.minimizer
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.221486647653181
 1.9891622925760526
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! What do you mean that using a step function to create `y` could lead to biased estimates?